# Why trigger not fire when updating

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I developed a trigger to insert a history data for transaction table.

```
Create or replace trigger his_trg
After insert or update
On trans_tb
For each row
Declare
  V_data number;
  V_seq number := seq_name.nextval;
Begin
Select data into v_data from another_tb where key = :new.key;

If (inserting or updating) and nvl(:old.id) != (:New.id)
Insert into his_tb (column1, column2,column3,column4) Values (v_seq,v_data, :new.data1, :new.data2);
End if;

Exception
When others then
Dbms_output.put_line('error');
End;
```

Now issue is when i insert new record in trans_tb and update on newly inserted record means,   records are inserted in his_tb.

But when i update already inserted record on trans_tb there will no insert happen in his_tb

Note: Am created trigger for trans_tb after 5 records are already created in trans_tb. And i made update on those 5 records will cause issue.

Comment: May be your insert fails - try raising exceprion insted of consuming it - and you may see where the problem is....

Comment: Could you put the structure of trans_tb with key information ?

Comment: when you update, do you modify the ID column?

Comment: Why hide all exceptions? All kinds of errors could occur and you would never know about  it.

Comment: The trigger you've shown won't even compile; you're missing a `then` and `nvl()` needs two arguments, and possibly other problems too - as well as squashing errors, which is never a good idea. I get that you've changed names to hide sensitive information, but please do so consistently and logically; and it helps to show relevant table structures and the inert and update statements you're making too. Basically, a [mcve].

Comment: As per your all guidence i resolved my trigger issue...there is change in table structure, so i corrected that...Thanks to all.